# Mean stack usage with ionic2 in betterway deploying using aws

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, mean-stack

can you explain me how to maintain server using mean stack with ionic2?is it better to maintain two servers(ionic and node js server seperate) or put only nodejs server?how we are going to put this app into aws with two servers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about servers and Ionic, I presume you are using Ionic to build a *Progressive Web App* and you are looking for a solution to serve it.

### Short answer:

No, you only need one AWS server instance to serve an Ionic web app. You just build the app and serve the `www` folder with any HTTP webserver.

### Longer answer:

## Preparing an Ionic Progressive Web App (PWA) for release in production

#### 1. Building

In your `package.json` file, you should make sure to have something like the following:

```
"scripts": {
     // ...
     "build:www": "rm -rf www && ionic-app-scripts build --prod",
     // ...
},
```

Now in your terminal run:

`npm run build:www`

#### 2. Releasing

Your app is built in the folder `www` ready for you to serve in production using any webserver like [NginX](https://www.nginx.com/), [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) or a custom [Node + Express](http://mfranc.com/node-js/node-js-simple-web-server-with-express/) webserver.

---

*Valid as of Ionic v3.4*

[Learn more about `ionic-scripts`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/app-scripts/), what they do and which other scripts you could possibly find useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.We are actually building mobile app using ionic.We have planned to use meanstack with ionic2 for backend.If i use only server which is nodejs i am able to fetch the data from using nodejs server not with  ionic serve or ionic-lab.If i use these commands it's not fetching the data from api becuase it's not referring to that server.If i want to fetch the data from nodejs server using ionic i need to create two services.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I have no idea what you are saying or what you are asking.

Comment: how to maintain server with ionic2 using mean stack and how to build app  and compile and deploy to aws

Answer (score 0):

Finally I understand the difference between serving ionic app thorough /WWW folder using nodejs and express and using api calls in ionic app.If you serve through /www folder it will be progressive web app not Mobile application exactly.If you just use api calls from nodejs server in ionic app it will be ionic Mobile app.

Deploying in AWS:
Create one instance for mongodb and one for nodejs in aws.
So that you will get all api calls through url.just use that api calls in your app to crud operations.